# How to convert a list of dictionaries which has type as string to a list?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, unicode

I have some data like this:

```
r = [{
  "id": "fhjgjj",
  "OneId": "sjgkhkshgkfh",
  "name": "test_one",
  "value": "/xyz",
  "pdiff": null
}]
```

Yes, 'r' is in JSON format.

I had r as unicode earlier (that's how data is obtained from an API).  So I did

u1 = r.encode("utf-8") which converts it to a string. (Unicode to string obtained here)

But if you see, r (above) is a list of dictionaries. What do I do to convert it to a list?

Comment: A list of what? What is your desired result?

Comment: Python doesn't have a `null` keyword. Is this JSON or JavaScript perhaps?

Comment: I want 'r' to be recognized as a list of dictionaries.

Comment: `r` is a list of dicts

Comment: @user2921139: `r` **is** a list of dictionaries. Do you mean you have a string now? Then you have JSON data and need to decode it as such.

Comment: Python gets 'r' as unicode  (JSON output)- so now how do I make Python recognize it as a list of dictionaries.

Comment: @user2921139: your post makes it look like it is a list of dictionaries *already*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module.

```
r= """[{
  "id": "fhjgjj",
  "OneId": "sjgkhkshgkfh",
  "name": "test_one",
  "value": "/xyz",
  "pdiff": null
}]"""

import json

r= json.loads(r)
```

Comment: Damn.. why didnt I think of converting it from Unicode to Python format directly.. Thanks Rawing.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a *string* containing that text, then you have JSON-encoded data. Decode it to a Python list of dictionaries using the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
import json

r_decoded = json.loads(r)
```

This uses the [`json.loads()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) (load string) to load from a string. If your data came from a file-like object (such as a HTTP response from the `urllib2` module), then use the [`json.load()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) to load the data directly, without you having to read the data manually:

```
r_decoded = json.load(file_or_response_or_similar_object)
```